# offsite_payments rails and payfast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, returnurl

I am trying to implement offsite_payments with Payfast in a Rails Application.

I managed to follow get the integration working to an extent to where I can process the payment in sandbox and then return successfully to the website.

I am struggling to get the subscription status set from 'unpaid' to 'paid' though. I have no idea how to use the ITN return variables to update the specific subscription.

Anyone willing to help a newbie, it would be much appreciated. I have spent weeks on trial and error, but it seems little bit advanced for my current rails knowledge.

Here is the PayFastController

```
class PayfastController < ApplicationController

skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

def paid
create_notification 'clientpass'

if @notification.acknowledge
  if @notification.complete?
    render nothing: true
  else
    render nothing: true
  end
else
  head :bad_request
end
end

def success

end

def fail

end

private

def create_notification(password)
@notification = OffsitePayments.integration(:pay_fast).notification(request.raw_post,    secret: Rails.configuration.offsite_payments['payfast'][password])
end

end
```

Thanks in advance! Please let me know if you need any more info.
Andries

Comment: Does your notify_url return a `200` response?? PayFast will not be able to post to the return variables to your notify_url if it does not.

Comment: Hi Daniel, it seems to return a 404 status, and I did some digging and seems to have to do with Application Controller protect_from_forgery... Any ideas? I tested it on a the production app on heroku...

Comment: The `404` returned by your `notify_url` will defiantly be the issue. PayFast cannot POST to a page that is not found. You need to see why the `notify_url` page is returning a `404` repsonse